# Web site providing tailored content... and the negative social side effect

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What's the (slightly pejorative) word for the way some websites provide content tailored to the "interests" (belief systems, etc.) of users, thereby preventing them (or at least greatly diminishing the opportunities) to discover other points of view?

Google does it. Twitter does it.

I regularly receives emails from Twitter, with suggestions and the latest "activity on the network" and it usually right on the money, introducing me to tweets on human rights, activism, social issues.

My problem with it is that those who need to hear of such things (the very people to whom I, as an activist, would like to reach) are those who, by the very same algorithm used by such web sites, would be prevented from coming across it.

I once saw a specific term for such an algorithm for "tailored" content.

Somehow the following questions feels connected to the feeling behind my question:
[Has the term ‘weapons of mass distraction’ gotten currency as a metonym for web sites and lowbrow mass media contents?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117285/has-the-term-weapons-of-mass-distraction-gotten-currency-as-a-metonym-for-web)

Comment: Clickbait, perhaps?

Comment: Captive website? Like http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but emails that would inform you about things that you are not interested in would be called **spam**. So, while I see your concern, I doubt your concern is valid: people that _want_ to know about the subjects you mention are not denied access to that information, people that do _not_ want to know about them do _not_ want to receive such mails and notifications, they would consider them spam. They are still able to find the information when they change their minds.

Comment: @Ste Thanks, but no. We cannot accuse a search engine like Google of clickbait. But by tailoring the search results to the "interests" of the user, the user is being prevented from discovering alternate results, differing point of views, etc.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks. I read the wikipedia article but it does not seem to relate to what I was trying to describe.

Comment: @oerkelens I see what you mean and to a large extent, I agree. However, the email thing was only an example. Besides, I could very well sign up for Twitter email updates on on what's hot on their network, regardless of my personal interests. That wouldn't be spam. Also, one must realize that for people to change their mind, they need to be exposed to alternate points of view. The excessive tailoring of search results prevents just that and furthers the political/religious/social divides.

Comment: @augustin: what you call "exposure to alternate points of view" is exactly what others call "spam". The necessity of it is a political view in and of itself. I think it is a huge leap to assume such exposure as a necessity, no matter how valuable (you think) those views are. I would certainly _not_ be pleased if twitter decided I "needed" exposure to certain political or religious views, I would close my account with them (cutting off _any_ exposure!)

Comment: Perhaps you are remembering the very negative feeling that grew up around the use of Pop-ups in the 90s and beyond? Thankfully almost never used now, but they did grind most people's gears for a while. Not targeted though, just forceful in the way they stole users' focus...

Comment: As an example of this phenomenon that is not politically loaded: some friends were discussing the food known as "cheese balls". In eastern Iowa, this usually refers to a bar food consisting of breaded, deep-fried cheese curds. The Californian in the group thought it meant exclusively the soft, cream-cheese-based balls of cheese (often rolled in nuts) served for dipping at parties. When each did a Google image search on their phones, one got all images of the deep-fried delicacy, the other exclusively the deli version—and a third friend had all images of the cheesy puffed-corn packaged snack.

Answer (score 3):

**Filter Bubble**

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble):

> A filter bubble is a result of a personalized search in which a website algorithm selectively guesses what information a user would like to see based on information about the user (such as location, past click behavior and search history) and, as a result, users become separated from information that disagrees with their viewpoints, effectively isolating them in their own cultural or ideological bubbles.

Comment: +1 You posted this at the same time as I was posting a comment on March Ho's answer. See my comments there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'Targeted' is often used to describe advertisements when they are chosen to specifically match the user's preferred product types (or at least what it *believed* to be their preferences by the system!)

'Presonalised' can be used to to describe content tailored to match an individual's content preferences

Comment: Thanks. "targegeted", "personalized", "tailored": these words exactly describe the whole process. But in my question I was looking for a term that is less technical or marketing-oriented, but more pejorative, describing the negative social side effects.

Answer (score 1):

[Echo chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_%28media%29) sounds like what you are describing, since competing views are excluded.

> In media, an echo chamber is a situation in which information, ideas, or beliefs are amplified or reinforced by transmission and repetition inside an "enclosed" system, where different or competing views are censored or disallowed.
>
> [Wikipedia]

Comment: +1. 'Echo chamber' comes very close to what I had in mind. Thanks. I still believe I once came across another word (with a similar pejorative meaning), but I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: Aha! I got it. The wikipedia article you link to, links to the following related terms. I think the word I was after was "Filter bubble", but I also previously came across "Spiral of silence" which is also relevant in my context. "Positive feedback" is more technically accurate, lacks the pejorative connotation but is equally relevant. If you edit your answer and add wikipedia links and relevant quotes of these 3 additional terms, I can accept your answer. Thanks a lot.